AWS: Glue Crawler + QuickSight
I have a batch application that creates a csv file everyday with the "transformed-dd-mm-yyyy.csv" format file name. Every file has name, price and some other fields but that's what I am focused on. I want to create a QuickSight graph that will show me the movement of price for each item by the time.
I thought about using Crawler that will create tables named the same as the file name, but I don't know how to do it. Can you help me? Thank you.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
